# Getting run time error access denied 2147024891 (80070005) while executing a jar file

Tags: java, excel, vba, jar, executable-jar

I am getting this run time error when executing a jar file using the WshShell.Exec

This is my VBA code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim WshShell As Object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim jar
Dim dictionary
Dim projectlocation
Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
projectlocation = Worksheets("A").rootPath.Value

jar = projectlocation + "\src\main\resources\loadproject.jar"

Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("java -jar """ & jar & """ """ & projectlocation & """")

Set WshShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

So what could be the problem?

Any suggestions/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `Worksheets("A").rootPath.Value` ? Should that be `Worksheets("A").Parent.Path`. Assign the command to a string so you can debug.print it and copy/paste into a cmd window to test. `s = "java -jar """ & jar & """ """ & projectlocation & """" : debug.print s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be MS defender and Windows 10 causing problems for wscript, see this article and solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vba-run-time-error-2147024891-80070005/f29d9747-f61e-4a09-b179-b16d103e2d9b

It says:

*After few search, the IT team found where was the issue.  In the windows 10 Security Baselines and the Microsoft defender ATP Baseline.  The following options, under Microsoft defender need to be on at least audit mode:

- Block Office communication apps from creating child processes
- Block Office applications from injecting code into other processes
- Block Office applications from creating executable content
- Block all Office applications from creating child processes
- Block Win32 API calls from Office macro