# Automatically Update the EdgeDriver in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

In this post: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996165/how-do-i-automatically-update-the-chromedriver-or-edgedriver-in-vba)  an answer was given that has worked for over 2 years and suddenly stopped working this week.

The .send command in the following code for Edge now generates an excel vba error "80070005 access is denied" for some reason.  Any ideas?  Could it be some Office update?
Using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 64-bit

```
Public Sub UpdateDriver(ByVal DriverType As dType)

    'URLs to the drivers' home pages to which we can grab the curr versions
    Dim URLPath As String
    Select Case DriverType
    Case dType.Chrome
        URLPath = "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home"
    Case dType.Edge
        URLPath = "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/"
    End Select
    
    'Grab the current Version # from the driver's webpage
    Dim Doc As New HTMLDocument, DriverVer As String
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", URLPath
        .send
        Doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    DriverVer = getCurrentVersion(Doc, DriverType)
    
    DownloadUpdatedDriver DriverVer, DriverType
    ExtractZipAndCopy DriverType

End Sub
```

results in Run-Time error '-2147024891 (80070005)': Access is denied

Comment: In which line do you get this error? Have you checked if the link urls have changed?

Comment: .send  line above.  Yes the link is still a valid link and has not changed.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508293/getting-run-time-error-access-denied-2147024891-80070005-while-executing-a-jar) says it is a Windows Defender issue and has a list of fixes.

Comment: When I use the go back machine and use the previous webpage (they recently updated it but it uses the same URL) which is "https://web.archive.org/web/20231021075301/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/" the .send line does not throw an error, but when I use the current URL which is "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/" then the error occurs at the .send line.  What is it about the new website content that is causing the error message to be thrown?

Comment: @dcooke570 perhaps the server has changed ... to a more secure more strict configuration