# The 119.0.6405.159 Chromedriver Is Erring with Chrome Browser 119.6405.0.160

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the ChromeDriver `119.0.6405.159` loaded for `Win64`.  The current browser is `119.0.6405.160`... now I'm throwing the error in the image, when Selenium begins opening an instance of the Chrome browser.  The updated ChromeDriver is in the `C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic` directory.  Is there something that I'm missing, as this has been the typical remedy for the Chrome browser updates?

[Selenium - Chrome Browser / ChromeDriver Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RchaE.png)

Comment: Try the fixes listed in this post.  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482658/automatically-update-the-edgedriver-in-vba#comment136604002_77482658

Comment: The current version of Chrome is 119.0.6045.160 so your Chrome driver has to match this.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I found that there were multiple installations of the ChromeDriver.

C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic
c:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Userdata
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic
c:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

The actual solve ended-up being the Programfiles (x86)...